# Restriction and boundedness of a map

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, operator-theory

Let $\mathcal{\hat{A}} = \mathcal{A} \oplus \mathbb{C}$. With $\mathcal{A}$ being a C* algebra that may or may not have a unit.

Show that for $x \in \mathcal{\hat{A}}$, the map $\hat{l}_{x}: \mathcal{\hat{A}} \rightarrow \mathcal{\hat{A}}, \ y \mapsto xy $ restricts to a map $l_{x}: \mathcal{A} \rightarrow \mathcal{A}$ which is bounded with $||l_{x}||_{\infty} \leq ||x||_{1}$ with $x = (a, \lambda) \in \mathcal{\hat{A}}$ given by $||x||_{1} := ||a|| + |\lambda|.$

I am not quite sure if/how I am supposed to show that the linear map $\hat{l}_{x}$ restricts to a map $l_{x}$.

But I believe the "boundedness" part follows since

$||l_{x}|| = \underset{||y||=1}{sup} ||l_{x}y|| = \underset{||y||=1}{sup} ||xy|| \leq ||x|| $.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that by $\hat{A}$ you mean the unitization. I will denote it by $\tilde{A}$ instead and I will establish a bit of different notation. Fix $x\in\tilde{A}$ and define $L_x:\tilde{A}\to\tilde{A}$ by $L_x(y)=xy$. This is obviously a linear mapping.

Note that if $y\in A$, then $L_x(y)$ in $A$; indeed, the inclusion $A\subset\tilde{A}$ is by identifying $A$ with the set $\{(a,0):a\in A\}$, so, if $x=(a_x,\lambda_x)$ and $y\equiv(y,0)\in A$, we have
$$L_x(y)=(a_x,\lambda_x)\cdot(y,0)=(a_xy+\lambda_xy+0\cdot a_x,\lambda_x\cdot0)=(a_xy+\lambda_xy,0)\in A.$$
This shows that the restriction of $L_x$ on $A$ does indeed take values in $A$.

I will also assume that by $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ of a bounded map you mean the usual operator norm. Note that for $y\in A$ one has $\|L_x(y)\|=\|(a_xy+\lambda_xy,0)\|=\|a_xy+\lambda_xy\|\le(\|a_x\|+|\lambda_x|)\cdot\|y\|=\|x\|_1\cdot\|y\|$ for all $y\in A$, so $\|L_x\|\le\|x\|_1$.